# Use @Autowire in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to use `@Autowired` in my servlet to bring in some external configurations.
Here is my servlet

```
public class DashboardServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

private String backendUserPassword="";
public DashboardServlet() {
    super();
}

private WebApplicationContext springContext;

@Autowired
BackendHostConfiguration backendHostConfiguration;



public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    super.init(config);
    springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
    final AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.autowireBean(this);
    backendUserPassword = backendHostConfiguration.getUserpassword();
}



protected void doGet...
```

However, my backenHostConfiguration is always null.  Can someone help me?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DashboardServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DashboardServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.apple.store.unifiedproj.proxyapi.DashboardServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DashboardServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dashboard/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If you're using Spring anyway, why are you being masochistic and writing servlets by hand?

Answer (score -1):

Declare the servlet as a spring bean. Declare in web.xml a servlet with the same name as the bean.

Comment: Can you give a sample of servlet as bean in web.xml?